# Glassfish javamail error

Tags: glassfish

I have an application that sends mail using glassfish javamail configuration. the application was designed on my laptop an deployed on a server which connects to the web using a proxy connection. The email is sent without errors on my laptop (Which is connected to the web via wifi) but when I try Sending on the server, i get the following error: 
Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1

the pictures below show the glassfish javamail configuration on the server
[image]

[image]

Comment: Ensure that the username you use has cleared the CAPTCHA word verification test that appears when the user first logs in. Also configure the proxy on your glassfish as here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/820-7203/gigbs/index.html

Comment: thanks Vitorino. I have done the configuration as shown in the link you shared but its still not working

Comment: if your configuration is equal to the documentation, you need for look for something missing in your network configuration, maybe a firewall is blocking the port or the timeout is too small. Try raise the glassfish loglevel and post here.